# bash - Add . certain number of characters from end of file

Tags: regex, bash

Given

```
variable=1234567890
```

or maybe

```
variable2=12345678901234567890
```

I need to modify the value so there is always a dot the 9th character from the end.  The value could be any number of digits long but the dot must always be right before the 8 last characters.

I am trying to parse a response from https://blockchain.info/rawaddr/ for Bitcoin address balance that always gives a value like `"final_balance":12345678901,` instead of 123.45678901 (Bitcoin is divisible to 8 decimal places).

I'm guessing this might be possible with sed, but I don't really know.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what if there are only 6 position in the number? Please extend your question to include expected outputs, given example inputs. Good luck.

Comment: btw `$variable` is an illegal variable name. `variable` is the name, `$variable` is its expansion.

Comment: @shellter It seems to always give at least 8 numbers. So for example if it was .01 BTC it would return 01000000 as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using [parameter substring expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_expansion)?

#### Bash 4

```
$ echo "${variable2:0:-9}.${variable2: -8}"
12345678901.34567890
```

#### Bash 3

```
$ echo "${variable2:0:(${#variable2}-9)}.${variable2: -8}"
12345678901.34567890
$ echo "${variable:0:(${#variable}-9)}.${variable: -8}"
1.34567890
```

Parameter expansion saves you spawning another process, so it's very fast.

(Side note: The space between the colon and the first index is necessary to distinguish the substring expression with a negative start-index from another type of parameter expansion:)

> `${parameter:-word}`
>   Use  Default Values.  If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to work for a minute but now I'm getting this error:
line 11: -9: substring expression < 0
Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: you'd get that error if you used the bash 4 version in bash 3, or if the name expands to fewer than 9 characters total.

Comment: I got it working using -8 instead of -9.  It seems to work correctly now.

Answer (score 3):

For this you can use this `sed`:

```
sed -E "s/[0-9]{8}$/.&/"
```

It catches the last 8 digits and prints them back with a leading dot.

#### Samples

```
$ sed -E "s/[0-9]{8}$/.&/" <<< "$v"
123456789012.34567890

$ v="1234567890"
$ sed -E "s/[0-9]{8}$/.&/" <<< "$v"
12.34567890
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sed command without `-E`

```
echo 12345678901234567890 |sed 's/[0-9]\{8\}$/.&/'

123456789012.34567890
```